# Relation between screen density and resolution

Tags: android

I was going through android docs explaining the concepts about screen density, different screen densities that are out there and resolution.

If I understand correctly,

`resolution is the total absolute no of pixels that are shown on the screen`

whereas

`density is the number of pixels per inch`.

Now, I was going through [this doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) which says:

> the system Gallery application displays photos taken using your Android devices's camera which are typically much higher resolution than the screen density of your device

This line got me confused again. How come it's comparing the resolution of the images to the density of the screen?

OR is it just saying that the resolution of images would be more than the resolution of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just unfortunate usage of terminology in the docs.

Pictures come at a specific resolution: X pixels high, Y pixels wide. If your screen is of the same resolution as the picture or higher, it can show the entire picture as it is. Otherwise, the picture needs to be "squeezed" into the available space.

Note that this is true irrespective of screen's density. Denser screens having the same resolution will simply be physically smaller because density is inversely proportional to the physical size of each pixel.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `squeezed`? reducing the resolution of the image?

Comment: @Yashasvi, yes. If you have an image at 1920x1080, but your screen is 1080x720, then the image will need to be compacted by the factor of 1.5 to be shown on the screen (assuming that you want to see the entire image).

Comment: okay. And how do you actually compact the image? You reduce the absolute total no of pixels that it contains? which means you reduce the number of pixels per inch? and which ultimately means that you are reducing the density of the image. Am I right?

Comment: Usually you don't need to compact the image yourself. Just set it to ImageView and the system will do it for you.
The concept of "pixels per inch" is applicable to device screen that has a specific physical dimensions, but it's not applicable to a picture in general. It's only after you show a picture on the specific screen that it "gets" some density which is equal to screen's density.

Comment: okay. Yeah I know the system will do it for me but I want to understand what exactly do we mean when we say compacting the image. I guess it's similar to the term `downscaling` as mentioned here : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: It's exactly that. Sometimes also called downsampling. I just tried to use intuitive terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your phone is capturing photos in a resolution of 4000x3000 pixels.

Assume you're using iPhone X which is having 458 ppi `pixels per inch` and the phone is having a dimension of 5.69x2.79 inches so the total pixels it can accommodate is almost (1125 x 2436 pixels) 
Which means in 100%zoom of the image it can fit only a portion of it on the screen.